# Look for files in the current directory that don't match a pattern

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, wildcards

How can I modify the pattern in the second instruction, so as to exclude nested directories? (such that `ls` returns only `foo.mp4`, not the content of `bar:`).

```
$ ls *
foo.mp4 foo.ogg

bar:
bar.ogg
$ shopt -s extglob
$ ls !(*.ogg)
foo.mp4

bar:
bar.ogg
```

PS: I use OS X.

Comment: `ls` does not automatically descend into subdirectories. Have you created an alias or function? What is the output of `type -a ls`?

Comment: `$ type -a ls`
`ls is /bin/ls`

Comment: Oh right. `ls *` *will* descend because you're explicitly naming the directory. My bad. Plain ls with no arguments will not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What was I thinking?!

```
$ ls *.!(ogg)
foo.mp4
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` rather than `ls`.  With `find` you can exclude one or more glob-expressions.  For your example (and OSX), you could do

```
find * -depth 0 -type f ! -name '*.ogg'  -ls
```

which produces something like an `ls -l` (on just files, given the `-type f`):

```
66294163        0 -rw-r--r--    1 tom              wheel                   0 Sep  9 20:12 foo.mp4
```

With OSX, the first column is the inode value, and then the link-count.  **`find`** does not provide as many options for listing as `ls`:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
drwx------  3 thomas  wheel  102 Sep  9 15:33 com.apple.launchd.OFStJ79qtq
drwx------  3 thomas  wheel  102 Sep  9 15:33 com.apple.launchd.VQsV1ae6bI
drwx------  3 thomas  wheel  102 Sep  9 15:33 com.apple.launchd.e6HBMt2vnS
drwx------  3 thomas  wheel  102 Sep  9 15:33 com.apple.launchd.he9U4OAIMI
-rw-r--r--  1 tom     wheel    0 Sep  9 20:12 foo.mp4
-rw-r--r--  1 tom     wheel    0 Sep  9 20:12 foo.ogg
```

but can be useful.

Comment: Came here to recommend `find` with the `!` bang operator for logical NOT. Have an upvote.